# PHP - How to duplicate products in a product list array depending on quantity value

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to write a shipping calculator, doing pretty good so far. The input is an array of products from an order. A problem I encountered is that some of the products in the product list have a quantity value more than 1. Since the calculator uses `foreach` alot, it would be nice to have all products separated instead of quantity value. Is there a way I can copy a product entry as many times as the value of the quantity field, so I get an extended array?

Comment: Could you please post some code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better solution would be to use a for loop - if your code indeed requires you to iterate X times where X is the quantity of products. Without seeing code, I can only guess as to the schema of your data structure, but this snippet may point you to the right solution:

```
foreach ($products as $product) {
    $productId = $product["id"];
    for ($i = 0; $i < $product["quantity"]; $i++) {
        // your code here
    }
}
```

I would advise against you approaching this problem like you outlined in your question. Creating a new array to simulate what a for loop would do is a waste of memory and CPU, and much less scalable.

Comment: Simply beautiful! I'm still a newbie with php, a for loop never crossed my mind, but it is of course the perfect solution. You guessed the datastructure right too, but I will keep in mind to post a code sample in the future. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Hard to answer without looking at your code, but would this do it?

```
$products = array_merge($products, array_fill(0, $quantity, $product));
```